# Drag and Drop icon question

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I am dragging item from a datagrid and while dragging I could see all of the columns in the selected record, being getting dragged. However I only want to show one column (maybe name or id of the record)? Is there a way to achieve this? Also, could I show an icon or image instead of the record while dragging.

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by extending the DataGrid to expose the `DataGridDragProxy` property. Check out http://dgrigg.com/blog/2006/11/03/datagrid-drag-image/ for a [working example](http://www.dgrigg.com/samples/flex/datagriddragproxy).

**The extended DataGrid:**

```
<mx:DataGrid xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridDragProxy;
        import mx.core.IUIComponent;

        /**
        * @public
        * class to use as DragProxy image
        * set the default value to the standard DataGridDragProxy class
        */
        [Bindable]
        public var dragProxyImage: Class = DataGridDragProxy; 

        override protected function get dragImage():IUIComponent
        {
            var image:IUIComponent = new dragProxyImage();
            image.owner = this;
            return image;
        }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

**Using the DataGrid:**

```
<controls:DataGrid 
    dataProvider="{dataSource}" 
    rowHeight="40" 
    dragEnabled="true" 
    height="140" 
    dragProxyImage="com.dgrigg.controls.CustomDragProxy" 
    allowMultipleSelection="true">

    <controls:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Image" dataField="image">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:Image source="{data.image}"/>
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Product" dataField="name"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Description" dataField="description"/>
    </controls:columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

Comment: That worked... but I had to make many hard coded changes in order to place the dragged item at right location under the mouse. But that also is not consistent if the resolution of my computer changes. But nonetheless, I got the idea and it is somewhat solving the issue (to an extent). Thanks.

Comment: @user503510, No worries. If my answer helped solve your problem, marking as the accepted answer and an upvote would be appreciated. :)